# Cómo listar registros por fechas almacenadas en una tabla de Base de Datos MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy tratando de listar los registros de una tabla en mi `base de datos`, pero quiero hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

- Mostrar la fecha
- Deberán aparecer todos los registros realizados en esa fecha, uno debajo de otro.

En la tabla `actividades_recientes` de mi `base de datos` tengo 4 campos:

- id
- task
- date
- time

En el campo `task` se guardan nombres de actividades, en el campo `date` y `time` se guarda la fecha y hora en que se ejecutó esa actividad.

Quiero listar las `horas` de esas actividades por día. Consultar la `base de datos` y mostrar una lista donde aparece primero la `fecha` y luego todas las `horas` en que se realizaron `tareas` ese día, y así sucesivamente.

Este es el código que tengo hasta el momento:

Archivo `procesar.php`:

```
    $obj = new Task();
      $consult = $obj->Lists();

     date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");
     $dateActual = date("Y-m-d");

    while ($result = $consult->fetch_object()) {

     echo "<button class='btn btn-default'>date = " . $result->date . "</button><br>";

      $consult2 = $obj->Lists2($dateActual);
       while($result2 = $consult2->fetch_object()) {
      echo "<span>". $result2->time ."</span><br>";
      }
       $dateActual = $result->date;
      }
```

Consultas en `MySQL`:

```
      public function Lists2($date) 
        {
        global $conexion;

        $sql = "SELECT ar.*, date_format(ar.date, '%d/%m/%Y') as date, 
               date_format(ar.time, '%r') as time, 
                u.user as User 
        FROM task_recents ar 
            INNER JOIN user u ON ar.iduser = u.iduser 
        WHERE date = '$date' 
        ORDER BY ar.time DESC";
        $query = $conexion->query($sql);
        return $query;
            }

        public function Lists() 
         {
            global $conexion;

          $sql = "SELECT ar.*, date_format(ar.date, '%d/%m/%Y') as date, 
                date_format(ar.time, '%r') as time, 
                u.user as User 
        FROM task_recents ar 
            INNER JOIN user u ON ar.iduser = u.iduser 
        ORDER BY ar.time DESC";
         $query = $conexion->query($sql);
           return $query;
         }
```

Lo que obtengo es algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual no esta muy bien, la `fecha` 31/05 se repite varias veces, no me agrupa bien las horas para un determinado día.

Lo que quiero lograr es algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seria como agrupar para cada `fecha` todas las `horas` en que se realizaron actividades. Pero me he liado bastante con esto y no consigo obtener una buena solución a esto.

Existe alguna forma de realizar esto, algunos ejemplos o códigos para conseguir solucionar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Qué tal con un `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM actividades_recientes WHERE date = @date GROUP BY time ORDER BY date DESC`

La declaración "DISTINCT" es usada para retornar sólo valores diferentes, así puede que no se te repita la fecha que dices..